# saveAll Cascade (Anuncio->Veiculo->Moto)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

My problem is as follows:

I'm trying to save the following objects:

```
Anuncio
    Veiculo
        Moto
```

But when I use **saveAll** only **Anuncio** and **Veiculo** are saved, **Moto** is ignored.

What should I do to save the bike.

Note:
Veiculo.php **hasOne** = Carro, Moto, Nautica, CaminhoesOnibus.

For more details: https://gist.github.com/2209394

Debug (save): https://gist.github.com/2209399

Comment: Can you add the code showing how you are trying to save ?

Comment: Here: https://gist.github.com/2209399

Comment: Please show the actual save() call.

Comment: Here again: gist.github.com/2209399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`saveAll()` is a wrapper function for `saveMany()` and `saveAssociated()`.

Try using `saveAssociated()` instead with option `deep` set to true.

`$model->saveAssociated($data, array('deep' => true));` This is necessary because one of your models isn't directly associated from the model you're performing the save on (apparently).

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array